# iOS table view in modal gets shorter every time view appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

Here's my set up:
I have a tab bar controller as my root view controller. In one tab, I present a modal on user action. The modal has a navigation controller, and view controller with a table view as it's root view controller. On another user action, I push another view controller. Every time I pop back to the table view, the content size seems to have shrunk. The table view gets shorter and shorter in appearance. This does not correlate to change in size of the table view. When I log i always get back the same tableView size and content size, but the content is getting eaten from below.

Comment: Are you using the `Storyboard`? If yes, review and comment on the resource below. If not, migrating to it will allow you to remove a lot of code, and possibly save you much time and sanity. Alternatively, you may want to post some code, in order to help the community figure out which view is improperly anchored.

Answer (score 0):

If understood properly, your setup follows this diagram:

[image]

Using exclusively `Storyboard`, `Autolayout`, the [ViewLayoutAssistant.swift](https://gist.github.com/SwiftArchitect/003be02e89204cad8fea) utility to emphasize views positions and sizes (*what makes the crosshair*), and exactly **0 lines of code**, the odd behavior you describe above cannot be replicated.

As a solution, I propose you do just that: move your code to `Storyboard`, and bring-in your business logic in this flawless interface.